# Uninstall a Magento 2 module

Tags: magento2, uninstall-module

I installed a Magento 2  module from here using this link https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar. using these commands

```
Include the repository: composer require sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar
Enable the extension: php bin/magento --clear-static-content module:enable Sebwite_Sidebar
Upgrade db scheme: php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Clear cache
```

But now I want to uninstall it using

```
sudo php bin/magento module:uninstall -r Sebwite_Sidebar
```

it says

> Sebwite_Sidebar is not an installed composer package

how to remove its structure database Mean to say completely remove it

Comment: how do you installed it if you don't executed `composer update`?

Comment: @LucaS  composer require

Comment: sorry i make confusion with `--no-update` option

Comment: @LucaS then you know any way to remove it ?

Comment: i tried with a module installed with composer and magento uninstall command works correctly....i read your comment below, great you resolve it

Comment: @LucaS  I didnt uninstall it is giving error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got deleted by doing this.

```
Delete vendor/Sebwite_Sidebar
run command composer dump-autoload
run command php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

If you installed the module manually:
  remove the folder `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>`
  drop module tables from database
  remove the config settings.

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'vendor_module/%'
```

remove the module `<Vendor>_<Module> from app/etc/config.php`

remove the module `<Vendor>_<Module> from table setup_module`

```
DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='<Vendor>_<Module>'
```

Then next follow the command upgrade and compile.

If you installed it via composer:

run this in console:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r <Vendor>_<Module>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I used  composer require sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar  that command to install it . And where I can execute these command in magento2 ?

Comment: Please find the updated answer at last line

Comment: Sebwite_Sidebar is not an installed composer package
 . Now I got this

Comment: php bin/magento module:uninstall -r Sebwite_Sidebar

Comment: still same error

Comment: your module is installed or not can you please clarify to me

Comment: it was in vendor folder ,  I deleted manually and run this command then I got

Comment: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 60

Comment: you removed the module, so your getting that error

Comment: my better suggestion is first install the module manually by creating the  app/code/Sebwite/Sidebar/ place the downloaded code under this, then run updrade and compile commands

Comment: then you can confirm your module is under app/etc/config.php

Answer (score 1):

For all future people who comes here, note that there is a bug on uninstall magento command line tool, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5797

Answer (score 1):

This module has no setup script, so it does not adds information to tables, except the `core_config` table. I think you should uninstall it using regular composer command `php composer.phar remove vendor/package vendor/package2` as described in the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove) and then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and other commands if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just Delete that entire module file(Directory) in your text editor and follow the commands.

1.Flush Cache

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

2. Clean Cache (optional)

```
php bin/magento c:c
```

3. Setup Upgrade

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Check it by:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```